# If/else Statement display

Tags: java, computer-science

I have this question, 
1)  What is displayed when the following program is run:

```
    class Q1
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          r(3);
       }
       public static void r(int x)
       {
          if (x == 1)
          {
             System.out.println("hello");
             r(10);
          }
          else
          if (x == 9)
             System.out.println("bye");
          else
          {
             System.out.println("good");
             r(x-1);
             System.out.println("bad");
          }
      }
   }
```

and in my logic, the result would be

```
good
good
hello
good
bye
```

But the answer is

```
good
good
hello
good
bye
bad
bad
bad
```

Why those bad on the bottom lines appear?
When the last r(9) is assigned to x, the program encountered if(x == 9) statement, so it should stop, that's what I thought.

Please help me out to figure out the process and logic in here!
I'm so confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your r(x) method invokes:

```
argument| x=1    | x=9  | other
--------+--------+------+--------------
  code  | hello  | bye  | good
        | r(10)  |      | r(x-1)
        |        |      | bad
```

so your invocation looks like

`r(3);`

```
good
r(2); //because r(3-1)
bad
```

where `r(2);` invokes:

```
good
r(1);  //because r(2-1)
bad
```

where `r(1);` invokes:

```
hello
r(10);
```

where `r(10);` invokes:

```
good
r(9);  //because r(10-1)
bad
```

where `r(9);` invokes:

```
bye
```

If you nest these you will get

```
r(3){
  good
  r(2){
    good
    r(1){
      hello
      r(10){
        good
        r(9){
          bye
        }
        bad
      }
    }
    bad
  }
  bad
}
```

which generates:

```
        (from)
good    r(3)
good      r(2)
hello       r(1)
good          r(10)
bye             r(9)
bad           r(10)
bad       r(2)
bad     r(3)
```

Comment: Thank you. Now, I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some parts of the program execution, both when r is 3, 2 and 10, the program prints 'good', then recursively calls r(2), r(1) and r(9) respectively. However, there is one more statement, which will eventually get executed when the called recursive function finishes its work and returns to the calling method. That part will print 'bad' for when r is 10, 2 and 3 respectively and in that order.

Answer (score 0):

In the else block:

```
   else{
         System.out.println("good");
         r(x-1);
         System.out.println("bad");
      }
```

Even though you are calling r(x-1) recursively, there is nothing in that method that exits your program or prevents the r() method from completing and the next line where your print "bad" from running.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling r() recursively. On the first iteration, you make it to the last else, where you:

1. Print "good"
2. decrement x by 1 //(x=2)
3. *Call r(2)*

because r(2) is called, your original call to r(3) is placed on the stack, and it will continue executing at:

print "bad"

when r(2) returns control

Follow that same logic down the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

given the function r(int x) and main.

At first you start with the function call:

```
r(3);
```

Since x isn't equal to 1 or 9, the program prints "good" and calls r(2);

This same logic happens again so the program prints "good" and calls r(1);

In the function call r(1); x = 1 so the program prints "hello" and calls r(10);

The same logic as with the first r(3) and r(2) happens for r(10) so the program prints "good" and calls r(9).

When r(9) is called, the program prints "bye" and does not call r(x).

At this point the program continues from the point where r(x) was called.

At 3 calls of r(x), x did not equal 9 or 1. so the program prints "bad" 3 times.